# Deltalake merge Pyspark - update only

Tags: pyspark, merge, delta-lake

I have a target table has 100 rows and an incremental table has 20 rows (updates)

When performing merge with **whenMatchedUpdate** using pyspark, in target table 20 rows is getting updated and remaining 80 rows are getting updates as null values , not sure where it is going wrong .

```
Target Table
+---------------+--------------+
|center_nbr|center_id|active_ind|
+-------------------------+-----
|   12345|  6559    |      Y|
|   56789|  14257   |      Y|
|   77777|  2218    |      Y|
|   88888|  2218    |      Y|
+---------------+-------------

Incremental Table

+---------------+--------------+
|center_nbr|center_id|active_ind|
+-------------------------+-----
|   12345|  6559    |      N|
|   56789|  14257   |      N|
|   77777|  2218    |      Y|
|   88888|  2218    |      Y|
+---------------+-------------

Final Target table after merge

+---------------+--------------+
|center_nbr|center_id|active_ind|
+-------------------------+-----
|   12345|  6559    |      N   |
|   56789|  14257   |      N   |
|   null  |  null    |    null |
|   null  |  null    |    null |
+---------------+-------------
```

Merge code:

```py
df_tgt.alias("tgt").merge(
df_incr.alias("up"),
condition="tgt.center_nbr=up.center_nbr)\
.whenMatchedUpdate(set ={"tgt.active_ind": "up.active_ind"}).execute()
```